# iOS Simulator Crashing without an error or debugger output?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, swift, ios-simulator

My iOS Simulator is crashing and not giving me any output or an error for me to try and fix. The moment the app opens the screen goes black for 3 seconds and then crashes and goes back to the home screen on the Simulator. I have already added an exception breakpoint it did not break at any point in my code. I have no idea what the problem is. Here is my code:

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var strWordValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var strInputField: UITextField!


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    performAction()
    return true;
}

@IBAction func performAction(){

        strWordValue.text = strInputField.text.wordValue.description

}
```

main.swift

```
extension String {
    var letterValue: Int {
        if let found = find(Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"),Character(lowercaseString)) {
            return found + 1
        }
        return 0
    }
    var wordValue: Int {
        var result = 0
        for letter in self {
            result += String(letter).letterValue
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

There may be an error in my code that I am "skimming" right over or a bug in Xcode. I am unsure about both.

Any ideas on how to fix this error would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Add some breakpoints to find out where it is crashing. 2. Look at the console  (Utilities/Concole.app) output. 3. Check that out IBOutlet vars are connected correctly.

Comment: Where should I start adding them

Comment: Add them everywhere. ;-) At the top of every method. See how far the app gets before crashing.

Comment: Why are you extending String and not just adding a method? Because `extension` is the new shiny?

Comment: Can you post the code for how to do that

Comment: If your process crashed and the debugger was attached, figure out where the crash was.  If you didn't have the debugger attached, a crash log will be generated for you.  Look at that.  You need to provide more information to get helpful responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether the problem could be related with this. Check your IBOutlet connection for UILabel and UITextField. Your class does noy have UITextFieldDelegate protocol and strInputField.delegate = self in your viewDidLoad method

Comment: All methods of `UITextFieldDelegate` are optional. The first comment states: "Check that IBOutlet vars are connected correctly."

Comment: Sorry I missed the first comment. UITextFieldDelegate methods are optional but textFieldShouldReturn function in the code will be never be called without UITextFieldDelegate hence shared that info.

Comment: The delegate could be set in the .xib.

Comment: Still not working? I put breakpoints everywhere and it did not do anything. It is still crashing.

Comment: Never mind it works perfectly fine. I had 2 `IBOutlet` connections.